# Processing a Yes/No Response from Bash User

Tags: bash

This very well may be stupidity on my part. I would like to accept Yes/No, True/False responses within my Bash script:

*test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGUMENT=$1

echo User passed in $ARGUMENT

OPTARG=${ARGUMENT:0:1}

if [[ "$OPTARG" -eq 0 ]] || [[ "${OPTARG^^}" == "N" ]]; then
    echo Decline
elif [[ "$OPTARG" -eq 1 ]] || [[ "${OPTARG^^}" == "Y" ]]; then
    echo Accept
else
    echo Invalid argument
fi
```

Here are some sample results:

**./test.sh 0**

```
User passed in 0
Decline
```

**./test.sh 1**

```
User passed in 1
Accept
```

**./test.sh 2**

```
User passed in 2
Invalid argument
```

**./test.sh No**

```
User passed in No
Decline
```

---

Now the stumper. Why is `[[ "${OPTARG^^}" == "N" ]]` returning true for any string!?

**./test.sh Yes**

```
User passed in Yes
Decline
```

**./test.sh ThisShouldNotMatch**

```
User passed in ThisShouldNotMatch
Decline
```

Comment: what happens if you quote this? OPTARG="${ARGUMENT:0:1}"

Comment: Nevermind. Goldilocks is right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
if [[ "$OPTARG" -eq 0 ]]
```

Will match any string, unless it is just digits.  Use:

```
if [[ "$OPTARG" == "0" ]]
```

Instead.

Answer (score 8):

Although the problem in your code has been [well explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119850/36502) by [goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/25985/goldilocks), I cannot resist saying that your code is needlessly long.  You could simplify it a lot.

The following is equivalent to your desired code:

```
echo User passed in $1
if [[ "$1" == [nN0]* ]]; then      # First argument starts with either n, N, or 0
    echo Decline
elif [[ "$1" == [yY1]* ]]; then    # First argument starts with either y, Y, or 1
    echo Accept
else
    echo Invalid argument
fi
```

You might also want to refer to [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).

Comment: Thank you, devnull. I will definitely use this trick in future scripts! I was torn as to whether I should accept your answer, but I think the distinctions in goldilocks' answer may be helpful for others.

Comment: @i_grok I did mention in my answer that goldilocks' answer points to the problem.  I simply presented an alternate approach that seemed more _readable_.  It's good to see multiple approaches to solving a problem come up.  Regarding which answer is accepted is a relatively trivial affair.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use `case`

```
read -p 'Do you want to Continue (yes/no?): ' 
case $REPLY in
       [yY]|[yY][eE][sS]) echo Accept             ;;
           [nN]|[nN][oO]) echo Decline            ;;
                       *) echo "Invalid argument" ;;
esac
```